# can't switch between activities in android

Tags: android, button, android-activity, switching

i am new to android development. i am to switch between activities on my app, i have done the code but when i run the app it doesn't work. when i click on the button which is supposed to take me to the second activity nothing happens.

this is the code on the main java class

package youngadults.camden;

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FrontPage extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.front_page);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, youngadultsp.class);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

}
```

this is the code on the xml page of the main class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frontpagelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/lg" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/uyounadults"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/umusicfan"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/uyoungadults" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/umusicfan"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ushop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:text="@string/umusicfan" />
```

So when I click on the button with the id "uyoungadults" it should take me to youngadultsp.class but unfortunately nothing happens.

Comment: you didn't add click listeners

Comment: Can you please add your manifest file code and another activity code?

Comment: @nikis look at `xml` file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `onCreate` method to something like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.front_page);
    findViewById(R.id.uyounadults).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent myIntent = new Intent(FrontPage.this, youngadultsp.class);
             myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             startActivity(myIntent);

       }
    });
}
```

Comment: when i changed it the (setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {   ) went red and says this "The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})"   and also its asking me to remove the Override bit

Comment: post your code please; or try pasting my code in your project.

Comment: press ctrl+shift+o to import classes

Comment: dude you have to use `View.OnClickListener` but you imported `DialogInetrface.OnClickListener`.

Comment: thats the only class that got imported when i presses cntr+shift+o im sorry this is my first android app that i am doing so i dont know a lot about this

Comment: delete that line and replace it with : `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

Comment: thank you very much its working now but its not showing the contents of the second activity I have one button placed there but its not showing in the app

Comment: please accept my answer if it solved your problem and ask another question for your new problem :)

Answer (score 0):

See your manifest.xml whether you have given the heirarchical parent or not in the activity where you want to go from the mainActivity.
It should be as:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YoursecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_your_second"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"//check this thing
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```